# Want to send email with multicoloured text

Tags: vb.net

I using vb.net code to send emails.  There is no problem in sending plain text emails but I want to use some formating (bold, coloured text et.)  I am writing my message body in a richtextbox but do not know how to do the formatting.

Also I want to insert picture.  Please help regarding that too.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You basically need to make a html file with css for the elements you want to be colored. This you add to your email as an attachment with mime-type set to text/html.

For images you add these as base64 encoded attachments and use their Content-ID as CID: reference in your html code.

I wrote a little more about this in my answer to this thread:
[Send email includes image like Outlook does?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13133052/send-email-includes-image-like-outlook-does/13133137#13133137)